# Is it possible to have custom bar width with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to use MPAndroidChart to generate a graph on my app. I need stacked values and custom bar width (depending on a duration).

A sample of the current implementation: 
[image]

Could someone guide me how to achieve that (the graph should be horizontal scrollable to display more values)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/335

Comment: Thanks. The current implementation is already a custom view, but is hardly maintainable. That's why i try to switch to a third party library.

Comment: Thanks @jaunvi. This seems close to what i'm looking for, but it's about the spacing between columns rather than individual column width, right?